# Set a resolution higher than the monitor naturally can display - Screenshots

Tags: screenshot, resolution, monitor

I'm looking for a way to do screenshots in a resolution of 2560x1600 pixel (current game: Skyrim).

My Display supports only resolutions up to Full-HD. Since I can't get higher in the Options-Menue (no possible option above Full-HD for me), I tried to modify the preferences.ini ("SkyrimPrefs.ini").

When I try to start the game, the following error appears:

```
Failed to initialize renderer.
Your display doesn't support the selected resolution.
```

Can this be "fixed" in a way? I mean, the screenshot for itself shouldn't care about the resolution of the monitor, it just needs the signal from the graphic chip, if I got this right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you screen cannot give a higher resolution than Full-HD, because it just misses the required amount of pixels.

You want to downsample the game, this means that you render the image, but then it will be downsized to the resolution of your screen.

This is not done in the preferences.ini, but in your graphic chip itself. Furthermore, I don't know if the screenshot depends on the framebuffer or the screen itself. You could try FRAPS, which gets its information from the framebuffer.

I cannot explain this thoroughly myself, but luckily there are other people out there which have done this already.

I don't know what graphic card you have or what your OS is.

A guide for NVIDIA: http://www.neogaf.com/forum/showthread.php?t=509076

A guide for AMD: http://www.neogaf.com/forum/showthread.php?t=472941

I hope this helps you.

Comment: EXACTLY what I was looking for, thank you very much! Got an Nvidia Card and your link for it worked for me! :)